# Is my accumulating snapshot design correct for my DW and my need

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, snapshot

I just discovered the accumulating snapshot design for DW.

I need to record bug info that come from my bug tracker. Bugs have some info (a bug number, a sentence ...). It also has status:
                 created,
                 canceled,
                 affected,
                 resolved

A bug don't have to go through all the status (it can go from created to cancel, or created to affected to resolved ...)

Here is my central fact table

> FT_Bug_Track
>
> ---
>
> idBug int
>
> BugSentence varhchar(100)
>
> createdDate DATE
>
> resolvedDate DATE
>
> affectedDate DATE
>
> canceledDate DATE
>
> FKStatus int

The status foreign key just link to a dimension that tells me in which status i'm currently in (created, canceled ...)

(Of course I also have others dimensions like project, client, typeOfBug ...)

Everytime my bug is changing of status, i'll put a new date where needed and update the FKStatus to the currently one

Is my design good for a DW and for my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea if it's a good design for your situation, that depends on what your requirements are, i.e. what you need to be able to show in reports. So if you don't understand clearly how the data will be used and what users expect to find out from it, you should do that first before making any big design decisions.

Having said that, accumulating snapshots work best if something goes through a (relatively) well-defined, stable series of steps, like a manufacturing process or a loan approval. Unfortunately, this is rarely the case with bug trackers: tickets can be re-assigned to a different person without changing their status; they can be re-opened and go through the whole resolution process again; they can 'bounce' back and forth between 'in development' and 'in testing' and so on. That means you can't know in advance how many dates and statuses will be required over the lifetime of one ticket (unless you have an unusually simple process).

I recently worked on some helpdesk reporting and came up with a solution using two fact tables. The first has one row per ticket and shows the current status only (new, assigned, closed, whatever), with timestamps for 'created' and 'last modified' only. The second fact table has one row per ticket modification, so you can drill down into the detailed history of the ticket. It's worth noting here that many common changes to a ticket don't actually change the status (e.g. adding a comment) so you need to decide what a 'modification' is in your case: any change, or only a status change?

The ETL process calculates and maintains ticket-level KPIs on the first fact table such as how long the ticket has been (or was) open, how long between submitting the ticket and it first being assigned etc. Report users (e.g. managers) are usually interested in durations between two specific events, and handling repeating or cyclical processes isn't particularly easy. For this reason I would try to generate most reports using the main (aggregate) fact table, and leave the second one mainly for interactive analysis, but everything depends on what you want to get out off the data.

Even if this doesn't answer your question, I hope it gives you some ideas.

Comment: Well thks for this complete answer.
I admit that I don't know what the user wants exactly so I'll have to go back to them later to be sure. What I know is that the main use will be to check how many bug are created, resolved, canceled ... per month

Comment: I was thinking about my problem and I think that SCD could also be a good solution cause I don't go through all the statuses. So with this solution I always know my current status and the previous one. My basic need is to know how many bug are created and with this solution I still have it easily.

Comment: Yes, if your basic need is a high-level overview of number of bugs per submitter, or per trouble area or whatever then it's quite simple to implement. Tracking the full lifecycle of every ticket accurately is not so easy, so if you don't need it then you can certainly go for a simple solution and avoid a lot of complex issues.